# get_posts() instead of query_posts() for a custom post linked with a custom taxonomy term

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I built 2 custom posts (firemen and mario) for my template, and I built for each of them 2 taxonomy (type-mario and the term game, type-firemen and the term game)
at the moment I use query_posts() for showing title of both posts linked with their term but I d'like to use get_posts() instead.

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'type-mario' => 'games', 'showposts' => 10 ) ); ?>
<p>Mario games</p>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
 <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
 </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>


<?php query_posts( array( 'type-firemen' => 'games', 'showposts' => 10 ) ); ?>
<p> Firemen Games </p>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
 <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
 </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

It work well but I'm pretty sure that it's better to use get_posts() to show those 2 title posts, but I don't know how to do that.

PS: Remember that there are 2 customs posts and not classical posts, the cause of I had to build a taxonomy for each of my posts with the same term ...

Thanks for your advices.

Here is a solution:

```
<?php $posts = new WP_Query(array( 
   'taxonomy' => 'type-mario',
   'term' => 'games',
   'posts_per_page' => 10 
)); ?>
<p>Mario games</p>
<?php while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
  <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've seen the documentation on [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) it functions similar to `query_posts()`.

The difference between the two is that with `query_posts()` it will modify globals so that you have the use of the "the_..." global functions.

With `get_posts()` it will return an array of post objects which you can loop through without affecting the current Loop if any. Additionally you can loop through multiple post sets.

**Note:** in the WordPress example, the `setup_postdata($post)` function is used, which adds the post object as a global so that you are then able to use the "the_..." global functions (doing this however will affect The Loop).

**Note:** `get_posts()` should take the same parameters as `query_posts()`.