# Outputting WordPress custom post type content by custom taxonomy and sorting that content

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm using this solution by @Ellum2009 (http://stackoverflow.com/q/4160319/705100) to output custom post types by taxonomy term. The example is taken from the link:

```
<?php $posts = new WP_Query(array( 
   'taxonomy' => 'type-mario',
   'term' => 'games',
   'posts_per_page' => 10 
)); ?>
<p>Mario games</p>
<?php while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
  <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This solution, however, does not allow further sorting of entries. It just outputs them last entry first. I'm thinking I might be able to create child taxonomies for each term and label them "first," "second," "third," etc. The user could then just check the appropriate box in the admin interface to control the sort order.

My question is, how would I then output that sorted content?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know much about taxonomy however, WP_Query does support an orderby and order argument - do these not work in your situation?

```
<?php $posts = new WP_Query(array( 
   'taxonomy' => 'type-mario',
   'term' => 'games',
   'posts_per_page' => 10,
   'orderby' => 'date',
   'order' => 'ASC'
)); ?>
<p>Mario games</p>
<?php while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
  <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: @user705100 , also you can change to 'orderby' => 'title' if you want to sort it by post title, just change the orderby value to sort it according to that value. 'orderby' =>'title date' for both is also allowed. More at http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: @Ryan-Kempt: In this case, I need to give the user the option to sort the items in the manner he chooses. Simple ascending or descending of the parent taxonomy isn't going to cut it.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your question fully, outputting this in a way that javascript can then sort may be the easiest solution.

Comment: I wonder if the output could ask for an array (first,second,third) that would sort by the taxonomy child term. Beyond my php skills, though.